# upload image form in ajax doesn't work

Tags: php, image, forms, upload

Hello I would like to upload some images to my server. It works when I'm not loading the page with ajax.load into another page. So with a direct link to it it works fine. But I would like to click on a link, open the upload form and upload the picture (all in one window). Is this because the page is refreshing before uploading or is it another problem?  don't know how to solve this.

code:

```
<?php
include('includes/connect.php');

if(isset($_POST['uploadImg'])){
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
$name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];

if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
     mysql_query("INSERT INTO images (itemID,imgPath,imgName,imgExtension,imgAlt)               VALUES (".$_POST['itemNumber'].",'upload','".$name."','".$extension."','".$name."')")or die('kan niet uploaden'.mysql_error()); 
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Uw afbeelding is toegevoegd aan item".$_POST['itemNumber'];
      echo "<a id='uploadNew' href='#'>Nog een item uploaden</a>";
      }                 


mysql_query("INSERT INTO images (itemID,imgPath,imgName,imgExtension,imgAlt)                VALUES (".$_POST['itemNumber'].",'upload','".$name."','".$extension."','".$name."')")or die('kan niet uploaden'.mysql_error());     
}

?>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
Toevoegen aan: 
<select name="itemNumber">
<? 
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items");
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                  {
                      echo '<option name="itemVal" value="'.$row['itemID'].'">'.$row['itemTitle'].'</option>';
                      echo "<br />";
                  }
        ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="uploadImg" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I don't understand the relation between the title and the question

Comment: You cant directly upload a file through ajax. You need to use hidden iframe or another method. If you fire up google youll see a myriad of solutions and plugins to help you.

Comment: this will help you to upload instant image, use this plugin http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the fact that the form is sent to the parent page before the AJAX is loaded. The Partial page that you posted is retrieved through a second HTTP request and doesn't have any POST parameters set.

Your best bet would be to add the php script in the parent page from which the AJAX is loaded. Also specify a "target" attribute in your form element so you keep track of which server page is handling the request.

Answer (score 0):

ajax not directly upload your image, you should have to use some plugin to upload the image,

Previous i have used this plugin (ajax.form) to instant [image upload](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/).

follow the link, in this link a simple example that how to use this plugin and upload an image.. http://blog.webtech11.com/2012/03/18/ajax-based-instant-image-upload.html